# How does Facebook generate suggestions?

Tags: facebook

Recently, I've received friend suggestions for my family members overseas - but here's the thing. I have no family members that use facebook, we share no common name, and we're not even on the same continent. In fact, I haven't communicated with them for over a decade.

Yet Facebook knows about them and knows that they are probably a good suggestion. My question is from a data perspective, where does Facebook get this information?

I'm not concerned about privacy, but rather the technical aspects involved. Is there a funky algorithm that makes it all work? Or is Facebook tapping into information about me that I have no idea about?

Comment: I had something like that happen to me. I was getting suggestions for people I didn't know were on Facebook. I try to use Facebook for personal things, yet it showed me two colleagues. I was later told by one of them, that Facebook will suggest someone who has looked for you.

Comment: I don't think that's actually the case - since the lead singer of Scar Symmetry was suggested as a friend (not a fan, but a friend) - and I can assure you he has no idea who I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook does do some weird stuff - I read that if someone does an import (gives FB permission to run through their gmail contacts for instance) and you show up in their contacts and they chose not to add you FB will still remember the connection and they could potentially show up as a suggestion for you.

http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2009-06-12-n15.html

http://consumerist.com/5301425/facebook-where-are-you-getting-these-crazy-friend-suggestions-from

Comment: Yeah, that sounds fair. However, as I mentioned, I haven't contacted some of these people at all using anything electronic.

Comment: I would guess that it's FB hitting their giant social network. Maybe you have common friends, or common friends of friends. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_network

Comment: I wonder why Gmail supports that when Google has its own concurrent social network.

Answer (score 3):

I did an experiment recently, if I have a person's full name and ip address, I could know who that person is? Where he/she lives? Which school they went to and other public information.

Such a facility can be easily programmed (and many have already attempted to). Think this way - I know a person's last name and location. Now I could track down everyone who has the same last name and reside in the same locality. This way I can have a simple social graph of a family tree. Match more details and I get a better picture of 'relationships' these people share. (Try it out).

I can't even imagine the amount of data a 200 million strong social network can produce. I guess they do it this way -
a) There are 4 people A, B, C, and D. 'A' has emails of 'B' and 'C' but not of 'D'. Both 'B' and 'C' have email of 'D'. Now I could say there is a 60% chance of A knowing D.

b) 'A' visited the profile of 'D'. This is the connect between them - A->B->C->D. Now, there is also a person 'E' who is directly connected to both A and D. So shorter chain -> A->E->D.
With these 3 pieces of information, I could there is a 70% chance that A knows D. In this case 'D' did nothing and got a friend suggestion.

So I think its quite easy to generate a social graph, all you need is some useful data and some motivation.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses information entered on your profile, contact list, messages, direct comments made, page visits, common friends, workplace/residence nearness. Basically all that a person has been doing to interact. This info is dumped into a log or a huge list, a big data. Every component of the fb page may create pieces that go in. This huge data is analysed for possible matches. Each factor is given a weight, say direct comments on someones page is a big score. so, all this data around Terra Byte range is churned by Hadoop Map Reduce on a Facebook cluster, then the result is put out for consumption by web services. These web services show the data to the user/possible put it in a traditional data base like MySql. If you imort contact info from your email etc then they are analyzed too.

[A simple friend suggestion using MapReduce](http://harisankar-krishnaswamy.blogspot.in/2012/07/friend-suggestion-like-facebook-google.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is one more possibility that exists in which you are suggested friends with no apparent contact what so ever like the questioner asked. That is when the other person searched for your profile using 'friends finder'. That way the algorithm used for suggesting friends gets the clue for new friend suggestion to the person whose profile had been searched.